# ignore vimrc when vim is called from mysql

Tags: mysql, vim

In my `~/.vimrc` I have some lines like load vim plugins, etc

when in MySQL I use the argument `\e` to try to edit the MySQL query, vim is opened, but some lines in the `~/.vimrc` file cause problems.

How can I avoid load `~/.vimrc` when I call vim from MySQL?

Comment: MySQL's `\e` uses `$EDITOR` / `$VISUAL` environmental variables. I would imagine if you are having trouble with using Vim with mysql's `\e`, then you will have trouble with Vim and any use of `$EDITOR`. Can you do `<c-x><c-e>` or `fc` on the command-line to edit a shell command? If that doesn't work properly then I think you need to debug your `vimrc` file to see what is causing the problem. Or I guess set `$EDITOR` to something like `vim -u NONE -N`, but i feel that is not in the spirit of having a useful `vimrc` file.

Comment: yes, thanks, that could be a first solution, but I try to find some way to add some conditional in the vimrc, something like : if vim is opened by MySQL stop to load configuration. Similar to the vim versions conditionals `if v:version >= 800`